# Id reset in Mysql with nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

When I delete an article I want to reset my Id.
This query works in phpmyadmin but not in my code :

```
connection.query("SET @num := 0; UPDATE article SET Id_Article = @num := (@num+1); ALTER TABLE article AUTO_INCREMENT = 1", function(error, rows) {
            if (!!error) {
                console.log('Error in the query');
            } else {
                console.log("Succès")
            }
        })
```

Comment: This has "bad idea" written all over it.  Why would you want to change your identifiers like this?  What would happen if another table has a foreign key relationship to this table?

Comment: Is it better to let the Id the way they are, even if it goes from 1 to 10 without 2 for example ?

Comment: Yes, it's better to let the identifier continue to identify the record.  Is there a specific problem you've encountered that you think this would solve?

Comment: Not really, I just tought it would be better to have continuous id, also thank you for your help